# Read data from HttpResponse using python script

Tags: python, django

I have one function in Python that returns json as HttpResponse for the client side as:-

```
def get_response():
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status':1}))
```

Now from the server itself I want a script to decode the value returned by the function itself and check the status value as:-

```
check_value = READ_THE_RESPONSE_VALUE(get_response())['status']
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
import json

response = get_response()
json_response = json.loads(response.content)
json_response['status']
```